# Why copy intialisation is used instead of direct initialisation when passing argument to function parameter by value

Tags: c++, function, parameter-passing, function-parameter, copy-initialization

I am learning C++ using the resources listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, I [came to know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72184101/12002570) that *copy initialization* is used when passing arguments to function parameters(by value) etc.

For example, from [decl.init.general#14](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#14):

> The initialization that occurs in the = form of a brace-or-equal-initializer or condition ([stmt.select]), as well as in **argument passing**, function return, throwing an exception ([except.throw]), handling an exception ([except.handle]), and aggregate member initialization ([dcl.init.aggr]), is called **copy-initialization**.

(emphasis mine)

**My question is** that is there is reason for using copy initialization instead of direct initialization when passing argument to function parameters(by value)?

---

To make the question more concise, lets look at a contrived example:

```
struct C 
{
    explicit C(int)
    {
        
    }
};
void func(C param)
{
    
}

int main()
{
    C s1(2);  //#1: this works, direct-initialization and so explicit ctor can be used 
    C s2 = 2; //#2: won't work, copy-initialization and so explict ctor cannot be used here
    
    func(2);                  //#3:  won't work, copy-initialization of parameter param and so explict ctor cannot be used here
    return 0;
}
```

As we can see in the above example, the function call `func(2)` won't work because here the parameter `param` is copy initialized instead of direct initialized and so the explicit constructor `C::C(int)` cannot be used.

##### Summary

**My question is** why does the C++ standard(committee) choose to copy initialize the parameter `param` instead of direct initializing the parameter using the passed argument `2`. I mean if `param` was direct initialized then the call `func(2)` would've succeeded.

Maybe there is a reason, like advantages of using copy initializing the parameter instead of direct initializing it or maybe there are disadvantages of using direct initializing the parameter instead of copy initializing it.

Comment: This allows you to introduce conversion constructors that have to be used "on purpose". If the parameter was a class that acquires a number of expensive resources and the user was under the impression that there was an overload taking `int` doing something a bit different, then not being able to prevent this conversion from automatically happening wouldn't be good... You can still call the function without introducing an additional object using `func(C(2))` because of copy elision...

Comment: The whole point of `explicit` is to make it so that such an initialization/conversion doesn't happen automatically without clearly stating to which type the argument is converted. If you changed the rule so that function arguments direct-initialize the parameter, what would you expect `explicit` to be good for?

Comment: @fabian: should be an answer not a comment

Comment: Your post sounds like you think there's some kind of penalty for using copy-init, other than banning certain constructors from being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is precisely so that this *does not* work.

The whole point of the distinction between copy-initialization and direct-initialization is to prevent implicit conversions in cases of copy-initialization. By using `explicit` in your constructor, you are declaring that you *do not* want integers to be converted to `C` *unless* the user spells it out directly.

When you attempt to call `func(2)`, the type `C` is not *explicitly* visible anywhere near the call site. Therefore, it should be copy-initialization and if `C`'s conversion constructor from `int` is `explicit`, the call should be disallowed.